# Attaching the console with the GUI in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, console, wxwidgets

I'm writing a wxWidgets GUI application, but it also uses some console objects.

I need a way of displaying stdout and accessing stdin; the best way to do this, would be displaying the console as well as the GUI.  This can be done if a user runs the program from the command prompt/shell etc, but the command prompt does not automatically open to view stdout when the application is ran.

I know this has to be possible, because when you run a console application, the console runs automatically.  I found one or two solutions that require the Windows API, but sadly my code needs to be cross platform (I'm developing this on Linux).

Answer (score 2):

The solution is very simple: use [wxStreamToTextRedirector](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_stream_to_text_redirector.html). This allows console output to be redirected to a text control. You could create a separate window for this and color it to look like a console. The link above provides an example.

Comment: printf seems to not work, only cout

Answer (score 2):

If using Code::Blocks, in project properties under Build Targets, there is an option to build the project as a console application. Choosing that will have the app run with the console attached.

Answer (score 2):

WxWidgets has macro's (wxIMPLEMENT_APP_CONSOLE, wxIMPLEMENT_APP) for showing the console (or not). Seems to work fine, you can pick the right macro depending on your preprocessor definitions.

```
class MyApp: public wxApp
{
    public:
        virtual bool OnInit();
};

#ifdef _DEBUG
wxIMPLEMENT_APP_CONSOLE(MyApp);
#else
wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);
#endif


bool MyApp::OnInit()
{

    MainWindow *frame = new MainWindow( TOOLNAME, wxPoint(50, 50), wxSize(600,400) );
        frame->Maximize();
...
    return true;
}
```