# wxWidgets GUI + Console/Emulating a Console (wxTextCtrl?)

Tags: wxwidgets

I have a wxWidgets GUI program, and I would like to have a standard console window attached to it for stdout/etc. to go to.

If someone knows how to do this (a GUI application *and* and a console window) that would be splendid.  However, from looking around, I suspect this isn't directly possible.

Based on [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457065/attaching-the-console-with-the-gui-in-wxwidgets), I got the impression that this could be simulated with a wxTextCtrl in a separate wxFrame.  If this is a good way to do it, are there examples of it being done anywhere?  Are there other ways to do this?

EDIT: I am looking to either have (or at least emulate as closely as possible) a console window--so, black background, white characters with fixed-width font, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect e.g. `std::cout` to `wxTextCtrl` using [wxStreamToTextRedirector](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_stream_to_text_redirector.html%5d) but it doesn't really replace a real console under Windows or a PTY under Unix because only the text output via `std::cout` will be redirected but not anything printed using `printf()` or any other functions. If you need the latter, you need to do something platform-specific and in this case you should tell which platform(s) are you using and what exactly do you need to do.

Comment: Yeah, I do need printf(...).  Actually, what I want to do is make a "console" that is as indistinguishable as possible from the console provided in non-GUI programs.

Comment: For this you need to use the normal console under Windows, there is no way to emulate it. Just make your application a console one (/subsystem:console) when linking and don't detach from it. Notice that you can still use GUI classes in "console" applications without any problem.

Comment: When creating in console mode, I have always gotten "unresolved external symbol _main"?

Comment: Either use IMPLEMENT_APP_CONSOLE instead of the normal IMPLEMENT_APP or -- probably better -- tell the linker to use WinMain() entry point even though it's a console application using the /ENTRY linker option.

Comment: I get an access violation in toplevel.cpp:495.  I think the problem is that wxTheApp is defined as: #define wxTheApp static_cast<wxApp*>(wxApp::GetInstance()), instead of wxAppConsole. Using /ENTRY instead results in a lot of LNK4210, and then a CRT invalid heap assertion error.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what goes wrong for you, this goes way outside the original question and this is not the proper place to have interactive discussions (wx-users mailing list is). Both solutions should work in principle but maybe I'm forgetting some steps.

Comment: @VZ. Thanks for indicating this point. I was searching this too. +1 for you.

Answer (score 1):

I recomend 'upgrading' from stdout to the wxWidgets logging classes, which are way more flexible.  [Here is an overview.](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.4/overview_log.html)

Comment: Is there an example anywhere of using these classes to emulate a console?

Comment: Several of the sample applications use the logging classes.  They do not 'emulate' a console - the point being that they are better and more flexible than a console.  With careful use of styles, background colors, and fonts you can make a logging window look as much like a console as you wish.

Comment: With wxLogWindow I was able to get something working, but I couldn't find a way to customize it to look console-like.

Comment: Do you know how to alter the appearance of a wxWidgets window by using   styles, background colors, and fonts?  Then you can either call the methods on your instance of wxLogWindow, or subclass  wxLogWindow and call the methods in the new constructor.